# Developer refuses to try to find a solution

Tags: internship, developer

I am an intern/working student and am currently working on a project dealing with continuous integration. 
However, the code I am loading is not complete so the deploy fails (obviously).
The problem is: Our developers deploy the same code from their development system and not from the location where everyone has access to it and where the code is supposed to be deployed from.
I explained my problem to the developers, they told me my idea does not work and I should ask my coworker for help. 
I told them that my boss and the coworker they were referring to gave me the task to deploy from that location because that's how it is supposed to be.
However, they refuse to even try to load the complete code from their space to the source control management. I even suggested several solutions, also suggested loading it manually so I can at least finish my work. 
Whenever I write them an email they answer 10min later asking if it works now, when I say no they don't try to fix it anymore. 
I even sent the mails we're exchanging to my boss, hoping they would listen but nothing works.

My boss is not in the office for a few weeks now and my coworker wants me to fix the problem myself. I feel helpless since our developers work in another country and I cannot talk to them personally.

How can I make sure they are really trying to fix the problem instead of putting me off?

Comment: If you have any QA purview, then reject the dev's check-ins if they fail CI. Revert the check-in and lob it back over the fence to them. Don't play their "does it work now" game. Also, there should be a policy or procedure governing or controlling the workflow and accompanying change. Do you know what the policies/procedures are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your priorities are not their priorities. Since they are not going to help you, try contacting their manager. Explain to him or her that this matter is very important to your manager and if it doesn’t get fixed, then your manager will be very annoyed with their team.

Then hope for the best. Look for other useful work to do until your manager is back. Also check if your manager can be contacted. The right email from him could be very helpful.

Comment: Well their manager is also my manager. I addressed the topic in one of our team meetings once again and we might have team call with the developers to find a solution. 

Otherwise I will have to ask my manager to send them the right mail when he is back. Thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: *"... try contacting their manager."* - I thought protocol is CI Manager is supposed to discuss with Dev Manager. CI Engineer should not engage Dev Manager directly. At minimum, it leaves CI Manager out of the loop an unable to answer questions from the CTO. Do you have thoughts on why CI Engineer should contact Dev Manager directly?